# Unable to create account --- Djoser, Django_Rest_Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, djoser

**My Custom Model**

[image]

**My Custom Serializer**

[image]

**My Custom Manager**

[image]

**My Error**
[image]

Comment: Please take a look at this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inherit from `AbstractBaseUser`, not from `AbstractUser`

```py
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # put your fields here 
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

and in **settings.py** file

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app_name.CustomUser'
```